# Why isn't my searching of a Python string working?

Tags: python, shell

Python noobie here. I can get "in" to work as normal when I use a normal string like "see spot run", but it's not giving me what I would expect from an html page. It ALWAYS returns "not found".

```
import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.cnn.com/')
searchTerm = "center"

if searchTerm in response:
    print("found")
else:
    print("not found")
```

Comment: because response is not the text. Try `response.read()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen) for urlopen.  It doesn't return a string, it returns a file-like object.  If you want the actual content of the page, call `response.read()`.

Answer (score 1):

For a quicker, more bandwidth and memory friendly solution:

```
if any(searchTerm in line for line in response):
    print("found")
else:
    print("not found")
```